# Angular Passive Event Listeners

Tags: angular, google-chrome, passive-event-listeners

It is quite stunning how the Internet is empty regarding this topic `how to make an event listener passive in Angular`.

I have a dropdown menu which, when scrolled on, throws an error in Chrome:
`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive...`.

Google's motivation behind throwing this error and the problem itself is quite clear to me, and I know the solution. I need to make something like this work in my Angular code: `document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => { e.preventDefault() }, { passive: false });` But it seems the solution is harder to implement than I imagined. Angular does not have a means of setting an event listener to `{passive: false}`, and the vanilla JS I pasted above simply does not work.

Has anybody come across a similar problem/solution?
Maybe there is a workaround?
Any related information could be valuable, thanks.

Comment: Hi SharisM, could you try using `https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener`? There might be option for you to use there or optimized behaviors.

Comment: Hello @mikegross, I'll give it a shot soon and we will see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @mikegross, tried it, but it did not work either. Maybe you could specify what exactly you had in mind? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As specified in https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-passive-events:

```angular
(window as any)['__zone_symbol__PASSIVE_EVENTS'] = ['scroll'];
```

can be added in the polyfills, which will make the event listeners for the scroll event passive

Comment: The page you linked has been marked for archival. This is a better link: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-passive-events.